# Tedious node.js SQL connection; want to insert multiple values from an array

Tags: sql, arrays, node.js, database, tedious

I'm running a loop and trying to insert the multiple values from an array while running it.

Here is the code:

```
function GetJobsToCourseID(index, jobData){
  if((jobData != undefined)||(jobData != null)){


    var extrArray = [];

    for(var i = 0 ; i< jobData.length; i++){
        extrArray = jobData[i];

    for (var j=0; j<extrArray.length; j++)
    {
      console.log(extrArray[j]);
        requestID = new Request("SELECT IDKey from dbo.Jobz where SubJobFamily ='"+extrArray[j]+"'",  function(err, rowCount){

        if (err) {
                 console.log(err);
                 }
         else {  connection111.reset(function(err){});
                         }


    });
      }
    }
  }

    requestID.on('row', function(columns) {
    for (var i = 0; i <columns.length;  i++)

    {  

      console.log(columns[i].value, "Please work");


      if (columns[i].value == null || columns[i].value == undefined) {
        console.log('NULL');
      } else {



      }


  }

    connection111.execSql(requestID);

    });
 }
```

As you can see I'm trying to insert the j element of my tempArray(I dont think it should work anyways, because of how Tedious connections work)

What would be the approach then - extracting each array element and populating it withing the SQL table using Tedious?

Comment: Your OR condition should be an AND, jobData could pass the if expression if jobData is null

Comment: yeah i guess...

Comment: any idea how to solve it? @RyanWilson

Comment: I would look into creating an XML document so that you can pass that to your query as a parameter and do one insert with all values contained in the XML

Comment: Wouldnt that require me to run the loop anyways on my request?

Comment: You would need to run your loop but you could populate all the values into one xml document that could be passed to one call to SQL for insert.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding a connection pool and an changing the second loops `var j` to `let j ...` 'tedious' is really tedious...

here is the code:

```
function GetJobsToCourseID(index, jobData){


  if((jobData != undefined)&&(jobData != null)){
    var extrArray = [];
    var newArray = [];
    for(var i = 0 ; i< jobData.length; i++){
        extrArray = jobData[i];}
    for (let j=0; j<extrArray.length; j++){
      pool.acquire(function (err, connection1111) {
                if (err)
                console.error(err);

requestID = new Request("SELECT IDkey from dbo.Jobz where SubJobFamily ='"+extrArray[j]+"'",  function(err, rowCount){

 if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } 
  else {connection1111.reset(function(err){});}});

requestID.on('row', function(columns) {
    for (var i = 0; i <columns.length;  i++){  
      if (columns[i].value == null || columns[i].value == undefined) {
        console.log('NULL');
      } else {   

          arty.push(columns[i].value);
          console.log(arty);  
}}
});
  connection1111.execSql(requestID);
});}
  pool.on('error', function (err) {
      console.error(err);
 });  
}}
```